# Starting with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, vk

I'm working **application for mobile devices** with autorization in social network, that uses **OAuth 2.0** protocol (vk.com). Looks like DotNetOpenAuth is good tool for this task, but I'm a little confused where to start. Is there any tutorial about how to set up DotNetOpenAuth? I need only autorize and do few simple requests like: getting photo, name, etc. Or, may be there is another tool I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing an OAuth 2 *client* that runs on mobile devices like Windows Phone, DotNetOpenAuth won't work for you at present, because it doesn't target that platform.

Not to fret though. OAuth 2 clients are often quite easy to write without the help of a library. There are usually just one or two URLs you have to send requests to and you're done.

Comment: Yes, I'm writing OAuth client, but it's not exacly for mobile devices: it's for Unity3D engine, thet can and will be builded for mobile devices. Unity3D supports .NET 2.0 libraries. Will DotNetOpenAuth run there?

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth requires .NET 3.5 or higher.